# Why is mkString not working in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, tostring

I can't get an array to print like a string normally in Scala

```
  val a = Array("woot","yeah","ok then").sorted

  for (i <- a.length-1 to 0 by -1)
    println(s"$i: ${a(i)}")

  val ab = ArrayBuffer(for (e <- a if e != null) yield e*3)

  println(ab.mkString(" "))
```

For some reason, this prints:

```
2: yeah
1: woot
0: ok then
ArrayBuffer([Ljava.lang.String;@5034c75a)
```

And I was expecting it to print `"yeahyeahyeah wootwootwoot ok thenok thenok then"`, that is, the items in the array (as strings) separated by a space. Why isn't it working and what am I doing wrong?

*EDIT:* ok, it was showing that because I was initializing `ab` to be a one-element `ArrayBuffer` with that array as the element instead of the elements of that inner array being separate elements of the array buffer.

Comment: Everything looks as expected, you got exactly what you asked for. Where exactly is the problem? Why do you keep nesting arrays and array buffers, what's the sense of it? The question seems to contain too much distracting information. Could you please focus on one single problematic `println`, instead of seven different `println`s? What's wrong with `println(a.mkString(" "))`?

Comment: The problem is I'm expecting it to print out the items in the array as a string separated by " ", not "ArrayBuffer(....)"

Comment: Again: what's the problem with the most obvious solution `a.mkString(" ")` then?

Comment: Well I'm using that (see simplified update) and even that is printing out Arraybuffer(blahblahblah) instead of the contents as strings separated by a space.

Comment: The content of the `ArrayBuffer` is a single element (the array generated by the `for-yield`) . The default `toString` of this single element produces the unreadable `[Ljava.lang.String;@blah)`-thingie. Separating the single element from itself by spaces doesn't help at this stage. Just don't nest arrays in array buffers, it doesn't make any sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print each element of the array, concatenated three times, with spaces between the entries, then it's just:

```
println((for (e <- a) yield e * 3).mkString(" "))
```

it gives:

```
ok thenok thenok then wootwootwoot yeahyeahyeah
```

(and this is the right order, because you wanted it sorted alphabetically, and `o` < `w` < `y`)

If you want to reverse the array before printing, you can initialize it to

```
val a = Array("woot","yeah","ok then").sorted.reverse
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise, expressive way of doing that.

I was mostly wondering why it was showing that type and figured it out: it was because I was initializing the ArrayBuffer ab as a 1 element array whose first element was the array. Doing println(ab(0).mkString(" ")) has the same effect as your code too. Thank you!

Comment: @JC You're welcome. Do you have any further questions or clarification requests? Otherwise, you can [mark the question as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant was

```
val ab = ArrayBuffer((for (e <- a if e != null) yield e*3): _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some shorter answer using more functional approach:

```
val a = Array("woot","yeah","ok then").sorted.reverse
a.map(_ * 3).map(elem => print(elem + " ")
```

Edit:
If you want to have a result in some new variable you can do that:

```
val string = a.map(_ * 3).mkString(" ")
```